# Changed chainset, bottom bracket, wheels and cogset and find these parts left over, and the rear wheel clicking?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, parts, sprocket

I just changed the crankset, bracket, wheels and cogset (my first bike repair obviously) on my specialised tricross, and after my victory tea realised I had these three bits left over, and not sure where they're supposed to go? Also the back wheel clicks when coasting forwards? Many thanks for your help in advance

Please see better quality pics below. The parts are Shimano claris (at least the crankset is, not sure about the bracket) and the wheels are Aksiums. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You said you *replaced* the chainset, bb and cassette, are you sure these are parts are from the new components? It will help if you add the new components brand and model to your question.

Comment: The first appears to be an adapter to allow a square crank arm to be placed on a splined crankshaft.

Comment: The bottom photo appears to be some sort of seal.

Comment: A regular, rhythmic clicking of the rear hub while coasting is normal.  Some rear hubs are louder than others.

Comment: All back wheels click when coasting.  I bet your old wheel's hub was a lot quieter than the new wheel hub, that's all.

Comment: Your new wheels likely has a noisier freehub pawls than the old. Those parts don't look brand new. Did you use used components?

Comment: The third one is a spacer that goes on the hub before the cassette is put on. It is used when a 10-speed cassette is fitted to an 11-speed hub and avoids axial movement of the cassette on the hub. So check if your cassette does not move left to right. If it does, take it off, place the spacer and then only the cassette.

Comment: Free-wheeling Mavic Aksium hubs are quite noisy.

Comment: Hi Argenti, Daniel, Criggie and Carel, thankyou all very much for your helpful comments. Daniel was right about the adapter, Carel was right about the spacer and I think Argenti's right that the black ring must be off my old components somewhere. Point also noted about clicking. Anyway all fixed now and riding like a dream, thanks again!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several (five) questions in your post, and it is hard to answer all of them at once. Comments seem to answer some of them, and I would refer to manufacturer's manuals of respective parts you've installed for identification purposes.

The third thing (silver ring) is Mavic's spacer for 10-speed Shimano cassettes placed on their freehubs. If you use 11-speed cassette, then you don't need it.